# Consequences of fitting a regression model with an intercept term when it should be through the origin

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis, linear-regression

Suppose a true model is $Y_i=\beta X_i +e_i$, where $e$ is the random error. 
Suppose instead we fit the model (using least squares) as $Y_i=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 X_i +v_i$, where $v$ is the random error.

What are the consequences of this specification error on the model?

Comment: The fitted curve will not exactly go through the origin, but close to the origin. Generally, the mean deviation will be slightly smaller.

Comment: @JJacquelin what do you mean by the mean deviation will be slightly smaller? thanks

Comment: It's difficult to avoid confusion if all the definitions of the terms used are not clearly given. So, please, defines what you call "true model", "regression equation" and what is your criteria of fitting (deviations between what and what ?).

Comment: @JJacquelin I have reworded the question, I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: With the model $Y_i\simeq\alpha_0+\alpha_iX_i$ you have one adjustable coefficient more than with the model $Y_i\simeq\beta_iX_i$. So, a smaller mean error is expected with $Y_i\simeq\alpha_0+\alpha_iX_i$ than with$Y_i\simeq\beta_iX_i$.

Comment: @JJacquelin does that mean that the model $Y_i≃α_0+α_iX_i$ fits the data more closely?

Comment: Generally yes. But "more closely" depends on  the criteria chosen for fitting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not model mis-specification. Your true model is still within the model you're fitting, simply with intercept equal to zero. So any results that hold for linear model with an intercept continues to hold here.

You may wish to compute the statistical efficiency of both estimators, by working out their Fisher's informtion. My guess is that the inclusion of an extra intercept term does not affect the efficiency.